# Tomcat8.5 SSL connector with goDaddy certificate

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, connector

I had followed the instruction to generate the key and certificate.  I was able to import the certificate successfully.  I can't get the connector correctly.

Here are the steps and the messages.

1. Generating Key

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore myKey.jks -dname "CN=dnsName.com
   ```
2. Generate Certificate Signing Request.

   ```
   keytool -certreq -alias server -file myCSR.csr -keystore myKey.jks
   ```
3. Download certificate from CA: copy myCSR content, past into goDaddy, and download 3 files: `serialNumber-root.crt`, `bundle-intermediate.crt`, `*.pem`
4. Tomcat Web Server SSL Certificate Installation:

   ```
   keytool -import -alias root -keystore myKey.jks -trustcacerts -file serialNumber-root.crt
   keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore myKey.jks -trustcacerts -file bundle-intermediate.crt
   keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore myKey.jks -trustcacerts -file serialNumber-root.crt
   ```

Everything is successful at this point.

5. Modify `tomcat/conf/server.xml`

a. gives me `java.lang.Exception: Unable to load certificate key E:\tomcat\certificate\myKey.jks (error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line)`

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="E:\tomcat\certificate\myKey.jks"
                     certificateFile="E:\tomcat\certificate\serialNumber-root.crt"
                     certificateChainFile="E:\tomcat\certificate\serialNumber-root.crt"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

OR

```
<Connector port="8443" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" 
    SSLCertificateFile="E:\tomcat\certificate\serialNumber-root.crt" 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile="myKey.jks" 
    SSLPassword="password" 
    SSLCertificateChainFile="E:\tomcat\certificate\serialNumber-root.crt" 
    keyAlias="server" SSLProtocol="TLSv1"/>
```

b. gives me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Alias name [server] does not identify a key entry`

```
<Connector 
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="E:\tomcat\certificate\myKey.jks" 
       keystorePass="password"
       keyAlias="server"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
/>
```

c. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: c:\certificate\myKey.jks`

```
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" 
        maxSpareThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" 
        clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="server" 
        keystoreFile="c:\certificate\myKey.jks" 
        keystorePass="password" />
```

Comment: Use the `keystoreFile/keystorePass` entries. The others are for PEM files, not Java keystores. `c:\certificate\myKey.jks`: these should all be forward slashes.

Comment: Thank you, EJP.  I got pass the error.

Comment: I created the key with dnsName.com as the first/last name.  
I got error when try to https://localhost:8443 in browser.  It said, the 
The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.
The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.

Comment: I add this to server.xml, I get out of memory error.
<Host name="dnsName.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      <Alias>www.dnsName.com</Alias>
      <Context path="" docBase="myAppURLafterPort#" debug="0" privileged="true" />
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
             directory="logs"   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
             pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />
 </Host>

Comment: Your server certificate aliases don't match: in the CSR, you used the alias `server` and when importing the signed certificate, you used `tomcat`. It's probably okay, as Tomcat will default to using the certificate with the alias `tomcat`, but there's no reason to keep both your unsigned and signed certificates in your keystore.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" instead of "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" ?

```
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" />
<Connector 
port="443" 
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true" 
maxThreads="150" 
scheme="https" 
secure="true"                   
clientAuth="false" 
sslProtocol="TLS"
keystoreFile="mySSL.jks"
keystorePass="changeit" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Now, I got SSL certificate installed and start up tomcat successfully, but I can't http://localhost:8443.
I get page 
can not be display message 
•Make sure the web address http://localhost:443 is correct.

http://localhost:8080/  still works

Any suggestion is sincerely appreciated.

```
<Connector port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true"   SSLEnabled="true" keystoreFile="E:/tomcat/certificate/mykey.jks" keystorePass="mypassword" keyAlias="server" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

end of tomcat log:
02-May-2018 09:06:14.192 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
02-May-2018 09:06:14.207 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8443"]
02-May-2018 09:06:14.207 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

Comment: Make sure you have the url right: https://localhost:8443 Browsers usually don't know that this a https-port and try plain http.

Comment: DrHopfen, Thank you

Comment: The important part is the httpS

Comment: To clarify your question, edit the question. Do not post a follow-up question as an answer to your original question.